# Method 'setMethods' is deprecated when try to write a PHP Unit Test

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I want to create a mock to replace a resource:

```
$gateway = $this->getMockBuilder('PaymentGateway')
            ->setMethods(['transfer'])
            ->getMock();
```

I got this warning:

> Method 'setMethods' is deprecated

How can I resolve this deprecation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From now on we are supposed to use either `onlyMethods()` (which would be the closest equivalent to `setMethods()` and `addMethods()`:

```
$gateway = $this->getMockBuilder('PaymentGateway')
            ->onlyMethods(['transfer'])
            ->getMock();
```

This is explained in the [PR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687) (linked from the method PHP doc directly, [as seen here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6dec48ce60c80bbcbb0f591c90e853aac28fe7df/src/Framework/MockObject/MockBuilder.php#L205)).

Comment: thank you for your answer : I replaced setMethods with onlyMethods and i got warning about  Class PaymentGateway does not exist !

Comment: That’s a different issue. Unrelated with the original question. You should probably pass the fully qualified class name. Or `PaymentGateway::class`

Comment: when i use addMethods my test is OK and i don't get warnings,  i understand that i sould modify my code to work with onlyMethods. Thanks

Comment: I wish the warnings populating in IDEs would point users to a deprecated functions replacement so we wouldn't need to dig around the internet for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed like this:

```php
$pageModel = $this->getMockBuilder(PageModel::class)
    ->setConstructorArgs($pageModelArguments)
    ->onlyMethods(['getHitQuery'])
    ->enableOriginalClone()
    ->getMock()
;
```

the `enableOriginalClone` did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same:

Before:

```
    $mockHttp = $this
      ->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Client')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->setMethods(['get', 'getBody'])
      ->getMock();
    $this->mockHttp = $mockHttp;
```

After:

```
    $mockHttp = $this
      ->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Client')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->addMethods(['getBody'])
      ->onlyMethods(['get'])
      ->getMock();
    $this->mockHttp = $mockHttp;
```